# Facebook embed renders witdh 0px height

Tags: ajax, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, embed, pjax

When revisiting a page with a Facebook embed, the embed has a height of 0px.

I've already discussed with Facebook and recorded some screencasts: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1562053057141539/

Is there a way to force the widget to recalculate it's height?

Regards,
Christian

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue? If so, how?